# Getting error while loading spacy - 'en_core_web_sm' library

Tags: python, spacy

I have tried running below commands, it shows as requirement already satisfied but I am still not able load '`en_core_web_sm`'. I have tried downloading the library from anaconda prompt and jupyter notebook as well.

```
 nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm',disable=['ner','textcat'])
```

Python version - `Python 3.8.3`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Screenshot of Commands:

[image: commands]

Screenshot of error:

[image: error]

Screenshot of anaconda prompt:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to install the `en_core_web_sm` model separately by using the following command after installing `spacy`

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

or

```
python -m spacy download en
```

I have tried the below steps in my jupyter notebook just now and it works good as below:

step1:

```
!pip install spacy
```

Result:

```
Requirement already satisfied: spacy in c:\users\user\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda\lib\site-packages (2.3.2)
```

step2:

```
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Result:

```
Collecting en_core_web_sm==2.3.1 from https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm==2.3.1
  Downloading https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1.tar.gz (12.0MB)
```

Comment: I already ran the first command using anaconda prompt, but still I am getting error.

Comment: your jupyter notebook must use another version of python. if you are using anaconda python, then it should work.

Comment: How do I make sure that my jupyter notebook is using same python as anaconda python?

Comment: based on your screenshot, your jupyter notebook is using the anaconda python. try to restart once

Comment: Yes, I opened the notebook through anaconda prompt. I will try restarting.

Comment: upated my answer